# How do I silence "VI_WARN_CONFIG_NLOADED" warning when using PyVisa?

Tags: python, node.js, visa, gpib

I'm attempting to use PyVisa inside NodeJS using the Python-Shell module. And I have the python code working, talking to the HPIB equipment. Only, I'm getting the warning-

```
c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\ctwrapper\functions.py:1222: VisaIOWarning: 
VI_WARN_CONFIG_NLOADED (1073676407): The specified configuration either does not
exist or could not be loaded. VISA-specified defaults will be used.
ret = library.viOpenDefaultRM(byref(session))
```

Its only a warning. But because I want to use stdin/stdout to push data into, and receive data from the python code, this warning is causing the wrapper to stop, causing the wrapper to callback with an error.

At least I think that is what's happening.

Any ideas?

Comment: perhaps you should specify a config which exists?

Comment: Being completely new to VISA programming, I'm not even sure how a config is created. I thought I could fix the warning by passing the path to the VISA32.DLL in the call to visa.ResourceManager. But that didn't work. How do I create a config?

Comment: Which VISA are you using? If you are using NI-VISA, perhaps you have enabled a Passport that can't be loaded (and possibly isn't needed.) See this [question](http://forums.ni.com/t5/Instrument-Control-GPIB-Serial/VISA-error-with-Agilent-E3647A/td-p/104745) on the NI forums.